Calculation of $H^1(\Lambda, R)$ of incidence algebra of a finite poset via Ext Groups
Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Consider the poset $P$ on the set $\{c,d,e,f\}$ defined by the relations $c\geq e, c\geq f, d\geq e, d\geq f$. Let $\Lambda$ denote the incidence algebra of $P$ over $R$. The derivation $ \varphi$ of $\Lambda$ defined by $\varphi(c,e) = 1, \varphi(c,f)=0, \varphi(d,e)=0, \varphi(d,f)=0$ is outer. Therefore $H^1(\Lambda, R)\not=0$. However as explained in the following paragraphs, when I calculate the same cohomology group via another method, I get a different answer.
Let $\bar{\Lambda}$ denote the incidence algebra of the poset $\bar{P}$ obtained from $P$ by introducing maximal and minimal elements $a$ and $b$, respectively. Also let $\bar{I}$ denote the parallel ideal and $\bar{F}$ the arrow ideal of the path algebra $R\bar{P}$ of the quiver obtained from $\bar{P}$.
In the paper, C. Cibils provides another way to calculate the cohomology of an incidence algebra. In particular, combining Proposition 2.1 and Proposition 3.6 yields the following:
$$H^1(\Lambda,R)= \mathrm{Coker}\{\mathrm{Hom}_R(b\frac{\bar{I}}{\bar{F}\bar{I}}a)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_R(b\frac{\bar{I}\bar{F}}{\bar{F}\bar{I}}a)\}$$
where the map whose cokernel to be calculated is induced by the inclusion $\bar{I}\bar{F}\hookrightarrow \bar{I}$ (this is not stated explicitly, but I fail to see any other alternative).
Below is my calculation for $\mathrm{Hom}_R(b\frac{\bar{I}}{\bar{F}\bar{I}}a)$. Note that given $v_1\in \{c,d\}, v_2\in\{e,f\}$ I denote the path $(a|(a,v_1),(v_1,v_2),(v_2,b)|b)$ from $a$ to $b$ with $(a,v1,v2,b)$ for ease of notation.
The differences of parallel paths from $a$ to $b$ are:
$$(aceb)-(adfb),(aceb)-(acfb),(aceb)-(adeb), (adfb)-(acfb), (adfb)-(adeb), (acfb)-(adeb).$$
The difference belongs to $\bar{F}\bar{I}$ if the paths start with a common arrow, so we are left with the following:
$$(aceb)-(adfb),(aceb)-(adeb), (adfb)-(acfb), (acfb)-(adeb).$$
Notice that the difference of any two elements from above set belongs to $\bar{F}\bar{I}$, for example
$$(aceb)-(adfb)-(aceb)+(adeb)=(adeb)-(adfb)$$
and
$$(aceb)-(adfb)-(acfb)+(adeb)=(aceb)-(acfb)+(adeb)-(adfb).$$
Therefore $\mathrm{Hom}_R(b\frac{\bar{I}}{\bar{F}\bar{I}}a)$ is generated by one element (which we can choose to be from $\bar{I}\bar{F}$). By a similar reasoning we can see that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(b\frac{\bar{I}\bar{F}}{\bar{F}\bar{I}}a)$ is also generated by one element, hence the above cokernel vanishes so does $H^1(\Lambda, R)$. However this is of course not possible.
Are my calculations of the above cokernel correct? If so, what is wrong with my interpretation of
Cibils' results?
The mentioned statements are included below for convenience.
$\textbf{Proposition 2.1}$
$$H^i(\Sigma_Q,R) = \mathrm{Ext}^{i+2}_{\bar{\Lambda}}(A,B)\,\textit{ for i $\geq$ 1}.$$
In the fourth paragraph of the paper, it is stated that "To a finite poset $Q_0$ (and Q its ordered quiver) we can associate the simplicial
complex $\Sigma_Q$ whose i-simplices are the chains of length i.  Cohomology of $\Sigma_Q$ with coefficients in R is isomorphic to the
Hochschild cohomology of the incidence algebra RQ/I."
$\textbf{Proposition 3.6}$ $\textit{ Let R be a noetherian ring, Q an ordered quiver, I the parallel
ideal, s, t two vertices of Q and S, T the corresponding}$ $\textit{ standard RQ/I-modules.
Then}$
$$\mathrm{Ext}^{2n+1}_{RQ/I}(S,T)=\mathrm{Coker}\{\mathrm{Hom}_R(t\frac{I^n}{FI^n}s)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_R(t\frac{I^nF}{FI^n}s)\}$$
